# NestJS AuthGuard that handles both GraphQL and REST

Tags: rest, graphql, nestjs, auth-guard

According to the docs, in order to use AuthGuard for the auth of GraphQL resolvers, we have to override `getRequest` method like this:

```js
  getRequest(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    return ctx.getContext().req;
  }
```

Most of my APIs use GraphQL, but the others use REST endpoints for handling file uploads. (I referred to [this](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload)) Now, I'm using two AuthGuards. One is for GraphQL in which I overrode `getRequest` like above. The other one is for REST whose code is completely the same except `getRequest` (this time I did not override it) and the way to extract `user` object from the request after calling `canActivate`.

GraphQL:

```js
// getRequest is overridden
const user: User = this.getRequest(context).user;
```

REST:

```js
// getRequest is NOT overridden
const { user } = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
```

Is there any method I can try to combine these two AuthGuards into one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not have something like this for the `getRequest` method:

```js
getRequest(context: ExecutionContext) {
  if (context.getType<ContextType | 'graphql'>() === 'graphql') {
    return GqlExecutionContext.create(context).getContext().req;
  }
  return context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
}
```

And now you just need the one guard. `req.user` will be populated the same whether using GraphQL or REST

Comment: This is fantastic!
But how can I unit test this?
I can't seem to mock the return value of 'getType' to be 'graphql'
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'TContext'.